# Snowflake - Invalid argument > types for function 'IFF': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), NULL)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 columns to look through, `name`, `name2` and `name3`, and only 1 column in each row has a value that looks something like this with a word followed by a list `randomword [m=444]`  I have to check each column then I have to extract the numbers in that list so from my example I would need `444`.
I've tried the below:

```
Select *,
CASE
 WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(?:\[m=)') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '[[]m=([0-9]+)'),
 WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME2, '(?:\[m=)') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME2, '[[]m=([0-9]+)'),
WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME3, '(?:\[m=)') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME3, '[[]m=([0-9]+)'),
ELSE null
END
from my_table
```

but now I'm seeing this error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 0 Invalid argument
> types for function 'IFF': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), NULL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition in your `CASE` expression isn't a condition. `Regexp_Substr` returns either a string or NULL. It does not return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` as is required by the `WHEN` clause.

Instead you'll want to test if the return from `REGEXP_SUBSTR` `IS NOT NULL`:

```
 CASE
 WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(?:\[m=)') IS NOT NULL THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '[[]m=([0-9]+)')
 WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME2, '(?:\[m=)') IS NOT NULL THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME2, '[[]m=([0-9]+)')
WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME3, '(?:\[m=)') IS NOT NULL THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME3, '[[]m=([0-9]+)')
ELSE null
END
```

That being said, anytime your `CASE` expression takes this form like `CASE WHEN foo1 IS NOT NULL THEN foo1 WHEN foo2 IS NOT NULL THEN foo2 WHEN foo3 IS NOT NULL THEN foo3 ELSE NULL END`, it's much cleaner syntactically to just write: `COALESCE(foo1, foo2, foo3)`. Those two statements give the same results.

In this case:

```
COALESCE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(?:\[m=)'), REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME2, '(?:\[m=)'), REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME3, '(?:\[m=)'))
```

Comment: thank you for explaining so clearly, but the THEN statements are different from my WHEN, in the first part I'm looking for [m= in the row, and if found then I want the numbers only within them so if a row has 'test [m=111]' I want only 111. With the CASE WHEN example you mentioned it doesn't go through each column and extract this. Instead it looks like its looking at the first column NAME and if it doesn't find it its NULL, how do I get it to then go to NAME2, NAME3, etc.

Comment: If it doesn't find it in the first `NAME` this case expression absolutely goes to the next `NAME2` column and tries that instead. It then tests `NAME3` if `NAME2` was null and finally it gives up and just gives back `NULL`. It should work just like you want it to.